# How do I replace matched regular expression without including the final character in XCode?

Tags: regex, xcode

I've got a number of places in files for a project with the following format: `func whatever() ->Bool {`. However, it looks like the standard Swift guide is to use `func nevermind() -> String` (note the space between the `->` and the start of the return type).

I am able to find all these instances by using `Regular Expression` option in the Replace sidebar with `->[^ ]`. However, this includes the first character of the return type. What should I type in the replace field to insert a space without bothering the next non-space character?

After [I asked over on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218641/how-do-i-replace-matched-regular-expression-without-including-the-final-characte), I realised I could brute-force this solution by replacing all instances of `->` with `->`(with a trailing space), then finding any `->`(two trailing spaces, since the markdown isn't being cooperative here) to undo over-corrections, but that is a very inelegant (though effective) solution.  Is there a one-step way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

(On XCode 6 or later) replace:

```
->([^ ])
```

with:

```
-> $1
```

For XCode 5 or earlier, instead replace with:

```
-> \1
```